# AJAX response never returns on hosting server in CodeIgniter application

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I have a CodeIgniter application were I am using jquery datatable to fetch data through ajax:

```
....
ele.dataTable({
                "searchable": true,
                "pageLength": 10,
                "sortable": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "processing": true,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "ajax": source,
                "order": eval(order_by),
                "columns": eval(jsonStr),
                "scrollX": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                "dom": 'Blf<"clear">rtip',
                fixedColumns: true,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'colvis'
                    }
                ]
            });
....
```

Everything works as expected until I try to fetch a big set of data, the returned json response will be big and the execution takes more time.

I tried increasing the `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time`:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

within the AJAX function call but still I do not get a response.

I am hosting my website at godaddy. This issue started happening after upgrading to the latest codeigniter version 3.1.6.

Please advise what is best to be done in this case?

Comment: does the same problem occur if you reverted back to previous CI version?

Comment: You will need to benchmark the Ajax endpoint, perhaps find out what is taking the longest to run then start adding improvements to the code to help the performance. Maybe you need to add some indexing on the right fields in your DB tables. Its difficult for anyone to answer this because there are so many things that could be causing the performance issues and such a lack of information.

Comment: You are using server-side processing mode with `serverSide: true` and expecting `10` records (`pageLength: 10`). Your response should not be that big. The problem must be elsewhere. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, no errors, I guess this is an issue with server resources. The problem is not always occurring. Yesterday, I checked the performance and it seemed well. I also made some bench-marking and profiling to track the resource consumption, memory usage, database query speed...etc. The results were normal. I think I shall be moving to a more stable server.